# How to get os name (ubuntu) in java program

Tags: 14.04, java

I want to get os name programmatically in a java program at runtime. I tried `System.getProperty("os.name")` but result is `"Linux"`. How to do this?

Comment: This question belongs to Stack Overflow in my opinion.

Comment: Linux *is* the correct name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that there is only three system properties to determine os details :

```
os.name : Linux
os.version : 3.13.0-74-generic
os.arch " amd64
```

ubuntu specific solution is to read these files :

```
/etc/*-release
```

for me :

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

and the java code:

```
File file = new File("/etc");
File[] list = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith("-release");
    }
});
for (File f : list) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(f));
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(s.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this obviously isn't StackOverflow I would say the this code has a rather large number of issues; predominantly the use of the ancient and outdated `File` API and the opening of any number of `Scanner` instances without ever closing them.